# Finding Records by Date in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is happens on Sqlite. I am probably missing something but I couldn't figure out what exactly.

**Console Output**

```
>> date = Task.first.date
=> Tue, 16 Aug 2011
>> Task.find(:all, :conditions => {:date => date})
=> []
>> Task.find(:all, :conditions => ['date = ?', date])
=> []
>> Task.find(:all, :conditions => ['date IS ?', date])
=> []
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "tasks", :force => true do |t|
  t.date     "date"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not a complete answer but hopefully will put your mind at ease that your syntax is correct**

I knocked up a quick app to test this and all your methods of retrieval work.  This was with an SQLite database also and there were no errors.

```
t = Task.create
 => #<Task id: 1, date: nil, created_at: "2011-08-23 14:32:27", updated_at: "2011-08-23 14:32:27"> 

t.date = "Tue, 16 Aug 2011"
 => "Tue, 16 Aug 2011" 

t.save

date = Task.last.date
 => Tue, 16 Aug 2011 

Task.find(:all, :conditions => {:date => date})
 => [#<Task id: 1, date: "2011-08-16">] 

Task.find(:all, :conditions => ['date = ?', date])
 => [#<Task id: 1, date: "2011-08-16">] 

Task.find(:all, :conditions => ['date IS ?', date])
 => [#<Task id: 1, date: "2011-08-16">]
```

My schema.rb:

```
create_table "tasks", :force => true do |t|
  t.date "date"
end
```

Comment: I am using Faker and Populator gems to add dummy records. I am assuming that there is a possibility that these gems are using a different date format when populating dates.

Comment: Please post a sample of how you are populating your data and I'll check it out.

Comment: @primary0..why dont you try running the query `select * from tasks where date = '2011-08-16' limit 1;` from your sql interface and check whether it returns any records..the problem might be with the column name `date`..try using another name for the column like `task_date`.

Comment: `date = Task.last.date.to_date` solves the problem, at least for now. I will need to do more research on sqlite date fields and Populator and Faker gems. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Even I tried in my local db and everything seems to work fine.

The to_sql method will return the query generated by rails. 
That might help you in debugging the issue:

```
Task.where(:date => date).to_sql
```